# symfony route change not taking effect

Tags: php, symfony, routes

this is my controller:

```
/**
 * \brief Change Password of currently logged in user

 * @Route("/changePw", name="changePw" )
 * @Template()
 */
public function changePwAction(Request $req)
{
    //controller code here
}
```

When I change the line

```
* @Route("/changePw", name="changePw" )
```

to:

```
* @Route("/changePw2", name="changePw2" )
```

This change does not take effect and the page still loads from `/changePw`

I thought that might be cache. So I tried:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

which didn't help either. It seems to be something obvious, but as I'm new to symfony I can not figure it out.

Comment: Maybe the route is defined elsewhere? Check `app/console debug:router`

Comment: try to debut all routes: bin/console debug:router do you see both routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to clear the dev cache for routing changes, if you are accessing the site using the `app.php` however and not `app_dev.php` then you will need to clear the prod cache for this to work. `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: The problem was, that I was using app.php and I had cleared the dev cache. However, as you said, when i switched to app_dev.php I didn't need to clear the cache anymore.